# cuda.net is based in CUDA Runtime or CUDA Driver?

Tags: cuda, cuda.net

I'm writing an article about CUDA and their wrappers and right now I'm stuck with what layer of CUDA is used by CUDA.NET or JCUDA.

As this suggests:
[image: CUDA Layers]
<sub>(source: [tomshw.it](https://www.tomshw.it/guides/hardware/graphic/20080618/images/nvidia-CUDA,Q-7-111103-13.jpg))</sub>

I guess as my program suggests when i use `CUBLAS cublas = new CUBLAS(cuda);` that I'm using a Library or a library on CUDA Runtime.

I'm right, or what is the best definition?
And wrapper is the best definition to CUDA.NET or brigde or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuda.net is implemented via Cuda Driver

Comment: Thanks! And in your opinion cuda.net is a language binding or a wrapper?